# np.percentile returns different median from np.median when inf is present

Tags: python, numpy, nan, median, percentile

When inf values are present in an array, under certain conditions np.percentile can return NaN as the median, whereas np.median can return a finite value.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.percentile([np.inf, 5, 4], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
/Users/tom/miniconda3/envs/alldev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy-1.16.0.dev0+45718fd-py3.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/lib/function_base.py:3947: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  x2 = take(ap, indices_above, axis=axis) * weights_above
array([4.2, 4.4, 4.6, 4.8, nan, inf, inf, inf, inf])
>>> np.median([np.inf, 5, 4])
5.0
```

In this case, np.median is able to correctly return 5.0 as the median value, whereas np.percentile returns NaN for the 50th percentile.

Comment: What's your question now?

Comment: Why is this happening?

Comment: That's because the functionality of those functions are not the same, not even close. You should check the source codes.

Comment: No, It's a good question. You can provide the answer after by yourself whenever you found it or my be someone else does that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first parameter is the data, the second parameter is the confidence intervals.  you not allowed to put an non number in the confidence interval

```
data=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
confidence=[5, 4]
results=np.percentile(data,confidence )

print(results)
```

output

```
 array([14. , 13.2])
```

values 13.2 through 14 will yield a 4 to 5 percent confidence interval